# Capture BCC Items in outlook after specifying

Tags: c#

How To Capture BCC mail items that are specified by the user inside BCC Column in Compose Email in outlook using C# ?

Comment: Are you looking for [_MailItem.BCC property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.bcc(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: I just want to trigger _MailItem.BCC once the user leaves BCC column after specifying mail items.
Currently in a button event I trigger _MailItem.BCC, and _MailItem.CC which is working fine..

Comment: As it currently stands, it's hard to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve. Please, elaborate more on what exactly you want to do, what you have tried so far. Here is a help on [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on StackOverflow.

Comment: I just want to show an alert ("Your BCC RECIPIENTS") after the user specifies the BCC in Compose mail item.
I placed a button in ribbon and onclick of button event I displayed the list of BCC Recipients in windows forms. Now I want to trigger that event automatically when the user completes specifying BCC mail items.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the [PropertyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.propertychange%28v=office.15%29.aspx) event of the [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
MailItem mailItem;
...
mailItem.PropertyChange += mailItem_PropertyChange;
```

And later in the event handler you can look for the changes to `BCC` property:

```
void mailItem_PropertyChange(string propertyName)
{
    if (string.Equals(propertyName, "BCC"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(mailItem.BCC);
    }
}
```